# How logstash handle nil value properly with plain formatter

Tags: logstash

I'm using logstash reading data from mysql to kafka. for save the disk space, I write output config as this:

```
kafka {
    codec => plain {
        format => "%{key1},%{key2},%{key3}"
    }
}
```

as I expect, by giving such input data:

```
{
    key1: value1,
    key2: nil,
    key3: value3
}
```

the output should as this:

```
value1,,value3
```

but the actual output is this:

```
value1,%{key2},value3
```

how to set output config to convert the nil with "", anyone knows?

Answer (score 1):

In your filter, add:

```
if [key2] { } else {
    mutate {
        remove_field => ["key2"]
    }
    mutate {
        add_field => ["key2", ""]
    }
}
```

If the field `key2` is missing or null, it will be replaced with an empty string as value.

Comment: hi, thank you, it works. there is a little thing puzzle me. by using mutate, the rubydebu output is like this: {"key1" => "value1", "key2" => [[0], ""], "key3" => "value3"}. I expect as this: {"key1" => "value1", "key2" => "", "key3" => "value3"}

Comment: Sounds like key2 was set to something, and the add_field turned it into an array.

Comment: What Alain said is true. `if [key2]` is false if [key2] doesn’t exist in the event, or [key2] exists in the event, but is null (cf https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.5/event-dependent-configuration.html#conditionals).